# Can I use Conda with a python version that was built from source?

Tags: python, conda

I am new to Conda and could not find the information that I was looking for. My team builds Python versions from source and we are now also looking to support Conda-Jupyter scenarios.

Conda creates environments with its own built version of Python but we are interested to know if it is possible to use Conda with the Python versions that we built from source instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on the conda forums and web I came to know that I would need to a build a custom Conda package to package my custom built Python. Since this is not a trivial task to do, I am abandoning this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this setting can help you:

Tools -> Preferences -> Python interpreter -> Use the following Python interpreter